# How to solve vb.net database connection error try catch database?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I try to register a user but when i want to save then the connection goes to 'catch' rather than 'try'.
I can debug the program but the data not save in the database..can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thank you.

```
Public Class DTRCLASS
Dim mDataPath As String
Public Shared DataModule As DTRCLASS

Private Function GetConnection() As OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Return New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mDataPath & "\dtrdb.accdb")

End Function

Public Overloads Function SaveMEM() As DataSet
    Return Me.SaveMEM("MEM_CODE")
End Function

Public Overloads Function SaveMEM(ByVal sortfield As String) As DataSet
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    b = Form1.Label16.Text & " " & Form1.Label15.Text

    a = Form1.txtlast.Text & ", " & Form1.txtfirst.Text & " " & Form1.txtmi.Text & "."

    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
    Dim SQL As String

    Try
        SQL = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS_PROF ( MEM_CODE, LOG_ID, NAME, COURSE_POSITION,GENDER," & _
        "ENCODER, DATE_ENCODED )VALUES ( @MEM_CODE, @LOG_ID, @NAME, @COURSE_POSITION,@GENDER,@ENCODER, @DATE_ENCODED);"


        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@MEM_CODE", Form1.txtid.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@LOG_ID", Form1.txtpin.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@NAME", a))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@COURSE_POSITION", Form1.txtpos.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@GENDER", Form1.cbogen.SelectedItem))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ENCODER", Form1.GuestToolStripMenuItem.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter(" @DATE_ENCODED", b))
```

> this `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` 
>   when debug it always get the message "Error in connection, ID or PIN already exist" [error message when i try debug using the coding 'MsgBox(ex.ToString')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYls5.png)

```
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



        MessageBox.Show("New Member is added!")
        clear()
        'RefreshDGV()


    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Error in connection! ID or PIN already exist!")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Function
```

[Line 91](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP39z.png)

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. In this case its called an Exception (how errors manifest themselves in .net). Include the message, the exception type, the stack trace, and any inner exception details. Use the edit link on your question to include that detail, do not include it as a comment.

Comment: Could be linked to the fact you have a space here `" @DATE_ENCODED", `. This should read `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@DATE_ENCODED", b))`. However as already asked, edit the question with the exception etc as that may help identify the issue right away. Also whilst you are at it, why don't you take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The exception will *tell you* whats wrong.  That code throws away the message and prints a useless message. `Name` is also a reserved word in Access SQL, so it should be escaped `[Name]`

Comment: MsgBox (ex.ToString)

Comment: @Igor thank you for reply..sorry because it was my first time to ask here and used this website..i have change the MsgBox to (ex.ToString) to identify the error and the error that i found is at 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()'  ..i dont know why it cant execute the data to the database..is there wrong in coding or database?

Comment: @IzreenNaim - There is almost nothing I (anyone) can do with that. Again, update your question with the exception `Message` and `StackTrace`

Comment: @Igor i have update the question..there are a image of the error exception message..is this helpful?

Comment: I did not see you buried an image link in there. In the future please copy and paste the exception details as text, not as a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

From your error image, the problem is "Datatype Mismatch in criteria Expression." Go look. This statement is near the top.

This statement should make you ask, 'what are the datatypes in the table you're inserting into, and what are the datatypes I'm attempting to insert?' There's probably a mismatch.

From your code snippet, it looks like several fields being inserted are text, but some fields seem to describe other data types. Like this one

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter(" @DATE_ENCODED", b))
```

But b is defined as a text like datatype here.

```
Dim b As String
```

The the fied name sounds like a date type.

If you convert your @DateEncoded Parameter to a date field within your insert statement(CDate is the function that does this), that should resolve the error for this field. Although there may be other mismatched fields, depending on what your table looks like. Here's your insert statement with the date conversion function included.

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS_PROF ( MEM_CODE, LOG_ID, NAME, COURSE_POSITION,GENDER," & _
"ENCODER, DATE_ENCODED )VALUES ( @MEM_CODE, @LOG_ID, @NAME, @COURSE_POSITION,@GENDER,@ENCODER, CDate(@DATE_ENCODED));"
```